# IIF condition with EXISTS return wrong value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I create a table type helper, so I create a simple IIF with exists condition like:

```
DECLARE @CustomerNameTableType [Helper].[VarcharIdTableType] 
INSERT INTO @CustomerNameTableType VALUES('');

DECLARE @HasCustomerName BIT = (IIF(EXISTS (SELECT [Id]
                                            FROM @CustomerNameTableType
                                            WHERE [Id] != 'Any'
                                               OR [Id] != '') , 1 , 0));

SELECT @HasCustomerName
```

As you can see I'm inserting value `''` but result of `@HasCustomerName` should be 0 because I have condition

```
WHERE [Id] != 'Any' OR [Id] != ''
```

Can some one explain me why I'm getting result = 1? Regards

Comment: FWIW, use `<>` instead of `!=`.

Comment: Also, that condition is always true.. rewrite it with [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) and it's `WHERE NOT ([Id] = 'Any' AND [Id] = '')`. It should be evident now that *[Id] cannot be both 'Any' and ''*. Fudging SQL syntax, that is then: `WHERE NOT (FALSE)` -> `WHERE TRUE`

Comment: Perhaps the desired condition is `WHERE [Id] <> 'Any' AND [Id] <> ''`? If so, I would write this (again, via DM) as `WHERE NOT ([Id] = 'Any' OR [Id] = '')` or, and as now can relatively easily visualized, simplified: `WHERE [Id] NOT IN ('Any', '')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to use `NOT IN` :

```
DECLARE @CustomerNameTableType [Helper].[VarcharIdTableType] 
INSERT INTO @CustomerNameTableType VALUES('');

DECLARE @HasCustomerName BIT = (IIF(EXISTS (SELECT [Id]
                                            FROM @CustomerNameTableType
                                            WHERE [Id] NOT IN( 'Any','')
                                            ) , 1 , 0));

SELECT @HasCustomerName
```